# Can you use Suppression fire into darkness?

Tags: savage-worlds

I had an encounter that took place outside in darkness and the map represented that. The rules for 'Darkness' are specific that targets outside of 10" (30 m, 10 squares) are not visible.

On of my players wanted to use suppression fire on two combatants that were 15" (45m 15 squares) away, which he obviously could not see according to the rules.

I did not want to allow it but it was argued that it was a 'pray and spray' maneuver and that it did not mater that he could not see the targets because he was just shooting in the general direction of the noise he heard.

Using the Savage Worlds Deluxe Explorer edition and taking into consideration that he could not 'see' the targets, is there any way to explain why he could not take this action or is it perfectly valid to take a literal 'shot in the dark' with suppression fire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SWD Explorer's Edition p.78: Firing Blind. Apply these rules to the suppression attempt. If they make their Stealth roll, they move out of the MBT and are not suppressed (No Spirit roll)

Comment: Wow I feel like a complete moron for not noticing that. Thanks!

Comment: Also in my explorer's edition deluxe the page number is 67.